# Solve the congruence using fast exponentiation algorithm to find an inverse?

Tags: divisibility

$$24x \equiv 17 \pmod{217}$$

I got this excercise from some book, the question is - solve the congruence, using fast exponentiation algorithm to find an inverse...Hmm, do you see some inverse here to solve, or is there just a mistake in the book?

Comment: Multiply with the modular inverse of $24$ modulo $217$. Faster than fast exponentiation is knowing $9\cdot 24 = 216$, so the inverse is $-9$.

Comment: Hi, you can use `\pmod{217}` (parenthesized mod) to get $\pmod{217}$.  Cheers

Comment: But if I'd want to use fast exponentiation, how could I do this? I don't see any way here.

Answer (score 2):

We show how to find the inverse of $24$ modulo $217$ by exponentiation.
Note that since $217=7\cdot 31$, we have $\varphi(217)=180$.
By Euler's Theorem, $24^{180}\equiv 1\pmod{217}$.

It follows that $24^{179}$ is the modular inverse of $24$. Now use fast modular exponentiation to compute $24^{179}$ modulo $217$.

**Remark:** Suppose that $a$ and $m$ are relatively prime. Then $a^{\varphi(m)-1}$ is the inverse of $a$ modulo $m$.

This is a lousy way of computing the modular inverse if $m$ is not large. And because there is no truly fast factorization algorithm known, it is not good for large $m$ either. However, if $m$ is known to be prime, finding $a^{m-2}\pmod{m}$ by fast exponentiation can be roughly competitive in efficiency with the Extended Euclidean Algorithm.